# Django Python Serializer Prefetch

Tags: python, django

I am using the [Django Python Serializer](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.8.x/django/core/serializers/python.py) to serialize a list of models which contain a many-to-many relationship. Even with prefetch_related, the serialization retrieves the prefetched-fields. For example:

```
class House(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    rooms = models.ManyToManyField(Door)

class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    num_windows = models.PositiveIntegerField(...)
```

Using debug mode I can see that the following function makes the expected 2 database requests.

```
getHouses():
    House.objects.all().prefetch_related('rooms')
```

However, when I attempt to serialize this object using the django.python.Serializer, it makes an additional query for the rooms in each house. Is there a way to configure the serializer to see the prefetched m2m relationships?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get rid of this is to build the map by yourself. You will need 2 seperate serializers, one for House and other for Room. 
While serializing, first iterate on houses query and serialize it, then run Room serializer for house.rooms which gives you serialized room which can be put as another key in serialized house using house_serialized['rooms_serialized'] = rooms_serialized.

Hope this helps.